# map print vs map println in Clojure

Tags: clojure, nrepl

I'm wondering why the following have different output orders in an nREPL

```
(map println [1 2 3])

Result:
1
2
3
(nil nil nil)
```

Versus

```
(map print [1 2 3])

Result:
(nil nil nil)123
```

Why does applying print show the return value and then display 123?

Answer (score 2):

Also to note, that this works in REPL, in the code you need to use `(dorun)`, as map produces a lazy sequence, and `dorun` actually forces print to happen:

```
(dorun (map print [1 2 3])) ;=> 123
```

Comment: You can use as well the following form to print the array: (print (apply str [1 2 3]))

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you may see a different order if you run the second one multiple times. `print` does not print any newlines, so the output buffer is not flushed. You could very well also see:

```
Result:
123(nil nil nil)
```

I suppose the first example could possibly change order, too, but the REPL has `*flush-on-newline*` set to `true` by default.

Answer (score 0):

It looks pretty much like result of output stream buffering.

You could forcibly print all data in output stream buffer by calling [`flush` function](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/flush):

```clj
(defn print! [& args]
  (apply print args)
  (flush))

(map print! [1 2 3])
; => 123(nil nil nil)
```